# Responsive grid layout for site or image gallery

Tags: jquery, grid, gallery

I'm making a responsive grid, for a gallery: [here's the example](http://codepen.io/KoniG87/pen/vyqds)

The plan was to make a grid that reorganizes itself when the device orientation changes. It works more or less fine if the container `#big_box`'s width is set to pixels (example 960px, 480px, 240px). Unfortunately when I try to use percentage values, it leaves many white spaces.

Is there any way to make it work with percent?

Answer (score 1):

this one is pretty awesome, it worked for me pretty nice: http://www.davidbo.dreamhosters.com/plugins/mediaBoxes/example/demo1.html

Answer (score 0):

I think using pure CSS, instead of mix JS and CSS, is better idea to make a responsive design?

Use Media Query.
Here is a [leaf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh653584.aspx).